# refactoring switch code in a Razor view page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, switch-statement

I am trying to optimize the below asp.net mvc code by reusing image tag using a variable. Could some one throw idea on optimizing this code/ refactoring code  by adding variables and reusing img tag?

```
@model int

@{
    switch (Model)
    {
        case 0:
        <text>
            <img title="abc" class="Container" src="@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.1_png)" />
        </text>
            break;
        case 1:
        <text>
            <img title="def" class="Container" src="@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.2_png)" />
        </text>
            break;
        case 2:
        <text>
            <img title="ghi" class="Container" src="@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.3_png)" />
        </text>
            break;
        case 3:
        <text>
            <img title="jkl" class="Container" src="@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.4_png)" />
        </text>
            break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review which is on topic at [codereview.se].

Comment: I disagree. It's not a code review - it's asking for how to refactor such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to change the model you pass you can achieve what you want by the following:
You set the title string and the file string in a switch and then use a string to make image source. You can see that code below.
But I would rather recommend changing the model itself in controller like @MatthiasG suggested, because it is not recommended to generate the data you show in the View.

```
@model int

@{
    string titleString;
    string filePartString;
    switch (Model)
    {
        case 0:
            titleString="abc";
            filePartString="a";
            break;
        case 1:
            titleString="def";
            filePartString="1";
            break;
        case 2:
            titleString="ghi";
            filePartString="2";
            break;
        case 3:
            titleString="jkl";
            filePartString="3";
            break;
    }
    var srcStrng = string.Format("~/content/images/{0}.png",filePartString);
}
<img title="@titleString" class="Container" src="@srcString" />
```

Comment: My image names are string like a_png, 1_png etc.

Comment: Then you can in switch you can also assign the first part of the file name. I will rewrite the example.

Comment: case 0:
            titleString = "Test";
            imgSrc = "not_png";
            break;


<img title="@titleString" class="Container" src="@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.@imgSrc)" />

I have issue getting 2 @ @ work in src="@Ur.Content and @ inside brackets.

Comment: You can't just reference the variable by another variable. Only with GetProperty().GetValue() like I wrote in the answer.

Comment: It throws error at GetType() cannot access no static method in current context. GetValue throws class name not valid at this point.

Comment: Can we try GetType for folder of images?

Comment: Then you probably should use this something like this: `string.Format("~/content/images/{0}.png",filePartString)`

Comment: I think you can also use Links.Content.Images as an array but I don't really understand what type is this variable.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just use the `Html.Image()` helper?

```
@model int
@Html.Image(string.Format("~/content/images/{0}.png",Model),new {@class="Container", title="..."})
```

Comment: Image names are string and they have different names. Could you please give idea on using string image names.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

- Your model provides more data: It could be a `class` or `struct` providing the title and image Url
- Find a way to generate title and Url out of the index, something like `imagepath = "constant text" + (model+1) + ".png"`

I think the first way is the cleanest.

An example:

**Model:**

```
public class ImageData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set;}  
}
```

**View:**

```
@model YourNameSpace.ImageData

<text>
    <img title="@Model.Title" class="Container" src="@Model.Url" />
</text>
```

Comment: title and url ar not in model. These are static.

Comment: Then expand your model. You asked for a refactoring idea, there it is.